# What can be the third parameter in fscanf in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, file, scanf

My `data.txt` file is as:

> 4 
>   73
>   67 
>   38 
>   33

I'm running this php file to **test fscanf**.

```
<?php

$handle = fopen ("data.txt", "r");

fscanf($handle, "%d",$n);
echo 'n:', $n; //outputs 4.
$grades = array();

for($grades_i = 0; $grades_i < $n; $grades_i++){
   fscanf($handle,"%d",$grades[]);
}
print_r($grades);
?>
```

The **output** of above script is :

> n:4 Array ( [0] => 73 [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php) => 67 [2] => 38 [3] => 33 )

I've watched this [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php) which does not explain about **what could be the optional parameters i.e.third parameter and others in fscanf()**.

Any sort of idea is welcomed.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php)?

Comment: Yes. I've , my question is about optional parameters.

Comment: Could you write it in answer with an example I'm not getting it.

Comment: Hmm... I knew the `fscanf()` function from C when I learned PHP and have never read its documentation until now. Indeed, only the first two arguments are required, the rest are optional. If the optional arguments are not provided then the function returns an array that contains all the values it read from file. If the optional arguments are provided then it stores the read values in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

> 10 73 67 38 33

In your file, you get

```
n:10Array
(
    [0] => 73
    [1] => 67
    [2] => 38
    [3] => 33
    [4] => 
    [5] => 
    [6] => 
    [7] => 
    [8] => 
    [9] => 
)
```

Simply because the first fscanf reads the first line ("10" in this example) into $n. That's what the third param is used for (see the mixed **&$** in the docs: http://php.net/manual/de/function.fscanf.php).

Ok, as I checked out the english docs at http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php I understand your question. The german explaination states: *"Optionale als Referenz übergebene Variablen, in welche die geparsten Werte geschrieben werden sollen."*

**Translation:** The optional param describes a reference in which the parsed values will be written into.

So, if you use $n for the first fscanf, the function will put the content of the first line (4 in your expample) into $n.

Comment: Okay . I understood that after your explaination and what about  the optional parameters. I have watched documentation. Nothing is explained.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
for($grades_i = 0; $grades_i < $n; $grades_i++) {
```

iterate 4 times because $n = 4

If you want to read the entire file into array use [file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function, here is an example:

```
 $arr = file(data.txt);
 print_f($arr);
```

Example using [fscanf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php)

```
 $handle = fopen ("data.txt", "r");

 $grades = array();

 while( fscanf($handle,"%d",$grades[]) );

 print_f($grades);
```

Comment: what are the parameters for scanf.

Comment: fscanf read from file according to format, and move pointer to the next line,